# Compare two date in TypeScript inside a condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, compare

In one refresh token I want to compare two different date.
Premised that I work in angular, the first value is **Date.now()** that obviusly return a current date, and the second parameter is one **expirationDate** (for example *2022-11-15T18:05:46.1645237+01:00*).

So if the current date is most of the expiration date, return me true. How can i make one IF for this situation?

Comment: `dateToCompare.getTime() > expirationDate.getTime()`?

Comment: `Date.parse()` will turn that expirationDate string into an integer like Date.now() which you can then easily compare. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse?retiredLocale=de

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a JavaScript Comparison operator ">" simply like this:

```
new Date() > new Date(expirationDate)
```